# How to increase the size of the int

Tags: c++, int

I'm looking for a way so that I can get big numbers.

I want to calculate 38^n for n>4000

So is there any way to do this?

Kindly help me.

Comment: `int` is exactly the size the compiler defines it to be. What you are looking for is not a bigger `int`, but either a larger integer *type* (`long` / `long long`) or a bignum C++ library, like libgmp.

Answer (score 5):

Look for a BigInt library like [this](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) one if the unsigned long long (64-bit integer) does not fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Since 38^4000 =

13626567354997617056329313518572669871071170880583693359544272980041303981882434734538430960058767177295025923983566648755876881186325460368486197224167007060233768247052629486933889789012295518920202064862370213656621579461608833913900821509100620666110600996588831934295625624174881269739475099253543291971949351958375909705904924125614847402331728307491174234130043557765333856587852136763450074228033057943275251763474040244718003871446278851718437538753553972738188449864081284199350852720967506441771879828977604092893701331872025324453791540567000401652841385183230548306942426747811381344952202704995790135045091236882434632638273097622784399474964071260288840973524580293683712707126132726032058096115050808212994474874887195248086357178602097170972380906461711265125678088349923203375968414475787300592583696065816150079128755226670110739203817178406747936072376786260989121289233458431976862204647875012437031767751018704749869460607366074818959142212892198396374773980500350327658780222474479129859007194457457829138631699788091425513210781560184664312254850195910716334354324281366251167877851974205334475355985568256387781089509361002196647952275789359155111023451749451415734405096655278295174255960345304122475081165484445003142760913586534250626764015379905517010658444442626228678332925600616931303695695506161883152099899363859336729182377570281814058896416875807664402882868124355445335565905063833617714010822965856571393423962785717867701811630985000479945840574458836679738068978432208205049488474929993540051593774645379459275410621407737459680323962561140718740797900009352381301734433124145413190718954715078693891773766465543820020118333909425037946747920952112324716580163881088322718499979305631739834146130913408498900815005646996682256912339033205133816486824614258926495495812784036447453990264570960357479488597566262100857318557132063094971671138328081636423205300001440991841875093227157189180046979201235997836871115178473793331951908545162574227413951298558070125899512700390047047940487152449438682512124512374465180907633872133729735427824770312681013603101057078687642650433926086042263469811785972516780935001257979167301396531650578909144617556401661596286655000890845598227443074432224649650421444669509917690850588828467680365214374983571440413011029311538006314308009334022145676697106884765702897820392205002104976510511690662873648924905859206045090301538364495227369714240000327397892685270724477432224051710235161915341380166322505403047479921207485985826617144630062427543646106264207676267960138097995365712065699367252327692166917027162817512355112577817759333185119496357726652263574955692412766427791636621561003248143162088338810765811925034175243098253477183777981530119336600325069531470597361199726340530012493284901312472359938906404036536403970381273042347532022592036037374925652036435508211829648726060002645001171965651585268749073280713101532058063840348319740158848595441587678957522413199351039043113142029907129705744137232342011968704198807114940460676009450036521225461344010852618106239118154966331660057415602614793721826584529397251289749725656538096388399695143315928518563068548192735206544682378537520506418007926073285706849973274222076317373033059304200101911951067149937028894562722109537797411167898225856420348308410350603384055632474339567057703010340688068370821291318903177717596801407315734010878564418695310254546381520276678538725157608043309023441709322160712160377986536483006949768428055070012131321307517369398293559849470345086292046748890778373027131007888477361435703338650286281943866790521895536089587012314596482938225348353910513764482608946308253045592163757729525262326745493201953185303485264102739959029696399931572287438132772357749175882967079565029225741296582036140259021566923027054743911617278986639492312193679025969190891540930024189366778105054430929215092236023487686440492543667079519662985565417362492072592025055258819162704173072662013949276074302392094104918002731442385963738154377544394436144830710895941012427657480393526992952298836599116927265835864794883149357772532128926114623377650330127681469398680908197842808781573649462943403899309504315010053951097502630531047921616001572581816853481632903644705002543359747980637999901147726746920478281033260422246532219801930828506609799922586505464736354853965408705166237575268884142550705915838361403803760633861291439873689266312094985645627825768264532068068383940009347237832839084518620736293338032805140684318825609037052029320710069076942327055511619384729507413979366221173731875081583527606225142331708054058056316566268463694297799208229967327456031980737573803309723678915050699869715272912792497268191176053411510542893000088350086703903267923064151320399321810627158761446660416500169785103732189707448149719408203646028631800570100383545558186048239744484408082627734589940230907845416949939893008652775458505691974437891034384581573026445318317396853368414228897325531497788743229729964241347151442038312944349207021462075732646443668171786595400861104506016915734670330338318506940647492024589840270503991235013262662584958056139456884168786647861529375426433055592755996647363095606998572938173742273727647855395827384610580791486231441743966364638926656177574517783395990477645234920662029069130520169839954328852889679297698894440289360920229577366598674693945253544348773443008431294122902200275761539883366488016392721682618754525310713687607682663191813572550150753228158785842023491267134367643177590897108661282968536031908401081453990449167116430269199694437799218382709284611544863462398344387527482864615346690281888178491568067973361859477877403761036289855293359103434207477896715048195648273965669239199756276403324120343903889368419203819744433704771664793914154135622085625251617910720554457686952006577578494073537754699513783351789231152535131897837873522492614650699226752457363727673079692328753548477123197857803197559269831202493927130425819248457221653733937060671839872590344351995222910813966529070591698808960588220021008665427193485211880949161819748058663187983592657186472030052147851033490886803897240924656263389646409848702846770248392608384734172415681411506756891468425081693839740848739676180437868697906407065835441491240347225077345140389966302714596712069918261923483301431653997283019346596069376

You definitely need some kind of big int library. You can find one quite easily on Google or even (if you plan only specific operations), write one on your own. For instance, the above result comes from my own calculator, which supports big integer evaluations.